# Products.Carousel stopped working - seems related to plone.app.registry

Tags: plone, carousel

I have Products.Carousel 2.1b3 installed in my Plone 4.0.2 site. It worked alright up until a day or two ago.

First symptom was that when clicking on the Carousel tab for a folder, it wouldn't show the tabs (only the message above the tabs - the one which says that I should go to Contents tab to edit existing banners).

I deactivated and then reactivated the product in the Plone Control Panel. It seems to have corrected the tabs not appearing problem. After that, however some other strange symptons:

- Some Carousels refuse to appear (it seems but I am not sure that the only Carousel appearing is the one for the Plone Site)
- The width and height configuration are not respected
- For the Carousel that does appear, there is no transition and the slider shows only the first banner

Finally, in the event.log, there is a Warning about plone.app.registry:

```
2011-04-07T17:45:55 WARNING OFS.Uninstalled Could not import class 'Registry' from module 'plone.app.registry.registry'
```

But I have no idea whether this started showing before or after the Carousel problems.

Any ideas on how I can fix it?

EDIT --

After some experimentation, it seems to be fixed by removing collective.carousel.

Does anyone know about any incompatibility between Products.Carousel and collective.carousel? Should one NOT install both at the same time in the same site?

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `bin/instance debug`  It's not uncommon to see errors reported there that you don't see in your normal log.
2. "Some Carousels refuse to appear" sounds likely to be a script problem - try using Firefox with Firebug to see if there are either any 404 (file not found) errors or javascript errors.
3. While OFS.Uninstalled **is** just a warning, I've seen sites completely broken by removing plone.app.registry.  However, this isn't the usual symptom.  I doubt it's the issue, but you can *always* add plone.app.registry to your buildout and see if your problems go away.

Comment: You probably want to run `bin/instance fg` which enables the development mode. `debug` will give you a database prompt, which isn't that helpful in this case. In Plone 4.1 this situation will improve, as you will always get errors reported during startup and not have them swallowed when starting in production mode (`console`, `start`)